# Access restrictions - force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites

**Situation**

We implemented some time ago some kind of proxy service for one of our force.com sites to create pdfs based on salesforce HTML. (The reason to implement this kind of solution was the the salesforce internal PDF processor (iText) was too unpredictable in terms of CSS interpretation.)

However, during the last week we noticed that we are not able to access our website from the external service.

**Question**

1. Is there some kind of rate limit implemented?
2. Is it possible that our server was blacklisted by salesforce?

**Details**

We are sending a request to salesforce that looks similar to:

```
{  
   "headers":[  
      {  
         "name":"User-Agent",
         "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.0 Safari/534.34"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Accept",
         "value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
      }
   ],
   "id":1,
   "method":"GET",
   "time":"2015-06-19T08:58:43.757Z",
   "url":"http://www.parx.com/de"
}
```

The external service is located in europe (ocean cloud).

Salesforce doesn't respond to the request.

Comment: Can you provide more details about why you cannot access it? What error are you seeing?

Comment: I added the request and maybe this is important to know: the server is located in europe.

Comment: And what;s the response?

Comment: There is no response. (Timeout). We tested the same functionality with a similar force.com site and everything worked fine.